# how to keep data from lines in file until condition met later in file python

Tags: python, file-handling

I suspect this is a repeat question, but I have searched for a while and don't seem to have the wording right to find the answer this question. Sorry if it is a repeat in advance!

I am trying to print the following information from a file I am reading in line by line.

gene-1 gene-2 gene 0* gene1 gene2

*referred to as ncRNA gene in the code

I have been able to get gene0, gene1, gene2, but I am having trouble trying to figure out how to buffer gene-1 and gene-2 until condition gene 0 (data[2] = ncRNA) is met.

In other words, I need to have variable information from previous lines, but only when a condition in the current line is met. I have thought about it in the commented out section below, but it seems like there must be a better way to do that (it will be a nesting mess). The file I am looking through is a gff file.

I don't know how to make a placeholder for the 'previous information' until the condition is met.

```
import sys
import re
gff3 = sys.argv[1]
f = open(gff3, 'r')

ncRNAgene= False
fgene_count=0

while True:
    line = f.readline()
    if not line.startswith('#'):
        data = line.strip().split("\t")
        ### this is not important to the question, just me dealing with the file format
        try:
            #my mis-guided attempts to get at this issue
            #if data[2] == gene:
            #line0 = f.readline()
            #data0 = line.strip().split("\t")
            #if data0[2] == gene
            
            
        ### the relevant information is in the third column of the line
            if data[2] == 'ncRNA':
                ncRNAgene = True
           
                print "ncRNA gene:", line
            
                while fgene_count <= 1 and ncRNAgene:
                    line = f.readline()
                    data2 = line.strip().split("\t")
                    if data2[2] == 'gene':
                        fgene_count = fgene_count + 1
                      
                        print "this is gene %s : %s" %(fgene_count, line)
        
            if fgene_count > 1:
                fgene_count = 0
                ncRNAgene= False
            
            else:
                continue

    except IndexError:
            if line.startswith('>'):
                break
    if not line:
        break

f.close()
```

This is what the part of the file I'm interested in looks like: I put brackets around the stuff I'm interested in.

> 211000022279165 FlyBase [exon]    14      1118    .       -       .       Parent=FBtr0300167;parent_type=ncRNA
>
> 211000022279165 FlyBase [gene]    14      1118    .       -       .       ID=FBgn0259870;Name=Su(Ste):CR42439;fullname=Su(Ste):CR42439;Alias=CR42439;Ontology_term=SO:0000011,SO:0000087;Dbxref=FlyBase_Annotation_IDs:CR42439,EntrezGene:7354392,GenomeRNAi:7354392
>
> 211000022279165 FlyBase [ncRNA]   14      1118    .       -       .       ID=FBtr0300167;Name=Su(Ste):CR42439-RA;Parent=FBgn0259870;Alias=CR42439-RA;Dbxref=FlyBase_Annotation_IDs:CR42439-RA,REFSEQ:NR_026633;score_text=Weakly Supported;score=0

Comment: Is this your actual indentation? Because there's a lot of problems just caused by that, which you have to fix first. You've got code that tries to use `data`, even if the line starts with `#`, which means you'll be re-using the `data` from a previous line. You've got an `else` which looks like it's intended to match a `try` rather than an `if`, which doesn't mean anything. And so on.

Comment: Meanwhile, it's not at all clear from your description what you want. What are the `gene-1` and `gene-2` from your description?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The commented out section is not my actual indentation, I'll see if I can fix the rest. Sorry that it is not clear what gene-1 and gene-2 are. I am basically trying to find the 'gene' information for areas surround ncRNA (or gene0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly what you mean here, but the general idea for problems like this is pretty simple: Just store `gene1` and `gene2` in local variables that you update whenever you find a `gene1` or `gene2` line, then use those local variables when you find a `gene0` line.

For example:

```
gene1, gene2 = None, None
for line in file:
    if matches_gene1(line):
        gene1 = parse_gene1(line)
    elif matches_gene2(line):
        gene2 = parse_gene2(line)
    elif matches_gene0(line):
        gene0 = parse_gene0(line)
        do_stuff_with(gene0, gene1, gene2)
        gene1, gene2 = None, None
```

Or, if there can be *multiple* `gene1` and `gene2` lines before each `gene0`, just use a list of them:

```
gene1, gene2 = [], []
for line in file:
    if matches_gene1(line):
        gene1.append(parse_gene1(line))
    elif matches_gene2(line):
        gene2.append(parse_gene2(line))
    elif matches_gene0(line):
        gene0 = parse_gene0(line)
        do_stuff_with(gene0, gene1, gene2)
        gene1, gene2 = [], []
```